# Azure App Service Dependency List (Linux App Service - .NET 8)

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Is there a list somewhere that shows all dependencies installed on Azure App Services?

Specifically, when upgrading a Linux App Service from .NET 7 to the newly released .NET 8, it would appear that there are missing dependencies that are no longer installed on the underlying machine/infrastructure.  Several NuGet packages related to graphics rendering that rely on libjpeg62 are not working on a .NET 8 Linux App Service that worked fine on .NET 7.

Comment: Have you checked it in KUDU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Installed Packages and Run time versions from KUDU Console =>  `Bash` from the deployed App Service.

Open the `KUDU` Debug Console => `Bash` from Advanced Tools

[image]

***or***

with the below URL .

```cs
https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

[image]

I have Installed some packages (as a sample to show) in my App and trying to retrieve the same.

I have referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) to get the list of dependencies in local.

To verify I have cross checked with  `dotnet list package` command in my local app.

***Local Output:***

[image]

***Deployed App - Bash:***

To get the list of Installed packages, navigate to the `site/wwwroot` folder

```cs
cd site/wwwroot
```

Run `ls` to see the list of files.

[image]

- Even you can check the same from the new UI of the SCM.

```cs
https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/fileManager
```

[image]

### Update

I have taken reference from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

- You can use `apt list` command either in `Bash` or in `SSH` to get the list of Installed Packages.
- Package along with version /Installation status /Environment is displayed.

[image]
[image]

- If you want to check only for a particular package, you can use `grep` keyword(used to filter and search with the given keyword).

```cs
apt list | grep libjpeg62
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like that lists the nuget packages and dlls uploaded with my app, however it doesn't show what's installed on the Linux machine in the underlying Linux App Service Plan... is there a way I can use bash to see that?  Specifically I need the underlying Linux machine to have libjpeg62 installed, which seems to have existed when my app was using .NET 7 but I can't confirm that it is still there when targeting .NET 8

Comment: Will check and let you know

Comment: Can you please share the screencap of your dependencies list from .Net 7

Comment: @StevenPfeifer - Please check the Update section in the posted solution.

Comment: Thank you, apt list worked perfectly and listed everything.  I tried to edit my question to include the lists on both a .NET 7 and .NET 8 app service, because they are different, there are some extra things installed but others missing.  At this point, I'll try to dig deeper to see if it's another issue with the NuGet packages I'm using specifically since it would appear libjpeg62 does in fact exist on the .NET 8 app service.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that it helped.